# Shiny: Make list of UIs relate dynamic

Tags: r, shiny

With `shiny` it is very easy to create `n` inputs by creating a list of UIs like so (I am using `...` to save space):

```
output$test <- renderUI({
    lapply(1:input$count, function(x) numericInput(paste0('numId',x),...))
})
```

Let's say I want to dynamically set each `numericInput`'s minimum to be the value of the previous `numericInput`. This won't work:

```
output$test <- renderUI({
    lapply(1:input$count, function(x) 
        if (x==1) numericInput(paste0('numId',x),...))
        else numericInput(paste0('numId',x),min=eval(parse(text=paste0("input$numId",x-1))),...))
})
```

It seems that using `eval/parse` to use the previous input as a parameter fails.

My next idea was to try adding this to the original code:

```
observe({
if (input$count>1) {
for (i in 2:input$count) {
updateNumericInput(paste0("numId",i),min=eval(parse(text=paste0("input$numId",i-1))))
}}})
```

Problem here is that observe doesn't know to respond when the `numId`'s are updated because none of the objects `input$numIdx` are actually in the `observe` statement, just strings that are turned into those objects when observe is run.

Any ideas on how to handle this? It would be very nice to be able to generate `n` inputs, and make them relate to each other dynamically.

Regards

Comment: I only quickly skimmed your question so this might not be what you're looking for, but if you want the code inside the observe to run whenever numId changes, you could just add a line `input$numId`. You don't have to use it to calculate any value or to do any assignment or anything, you could just have that be a whole line on its own, and that'll cause the observer to depend on that reactive value

Comment: When creating the `ui` elements wouldn't you be setting the values too? The issue you will be facing when doing it for all is that they will all look at first slider and then update the values